# Search Wikipedia and Return a Link Through Java

Tags: java, mediawiki, wikipedia

For my work, I need to be able to use Java to link places on our map of the world to their respective Wikipedia article, if there is one.

I do not need to read or edit the text. I just want to be able to post the first URL that comes up for Wikipedia when searching for a specific place name. I can do this easily for one or two places, but there are literally billions of places to link together.

I have tried to use MediaWiki, but I'm guessing there's a method I'm not seeing that can just return the URL of the best result for a search. If so, how do I make it work through Java? I have little experience with API's.

Is there a quick and easy way to make a search on Wikipedia through Java and then return the URL to the best answer?

Comment: do you want to map geo coordinates to article or name to article?

Comment: The name is better because geographic coordinates for the same place might differ from one site to the next but still both be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, Wikipedia has been successfully categorized just the way I need it on an auxiliary website, DBpedia.org. It's wonderful! If anyone ever needs to be able to quickly grab data from a Wiki site, DBpedia.org has it all listed out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can query wiki API with something like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=New%20York&limit=10&format=json
```

(here you can read more abot wiki API: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) And then extract first link from JSON

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This isn't exactly what I need. I already have this functionality and it requires a little more hands-on than my team has time for. Really, we just want a direct link to the wikipedia page, not any of the information on the page. Thanks a lot for your response!